# Contour plot using gr() with an interpolated function in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, interpolation, contour

I am trying get familiar with packages in Julia like `Interpolations.jl` and `Plots.jl`. The contour plot in Julia using the GR backend is very simple as shown in the link:
https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/examples/gr/#contours
And to carry out interpolation using `Interpolations.jl`:
https://github.com/JuliaMath/Interpolations.jl/blob/master/doc/Interpolations.jl.ipynb

I tried to make a contour plot using an interpolated function as following:

```
using Interpolations
using Plots
gr()

xs = 1:5
ys = 1:8
g = Float64[(3x + y ^ 2) * abs(sin(x) + cos(y)) for x in xs, y in ys]

gitp_quad2d = interpolate(g, BSpline(Quadratic(Line(OnCell()))))

xc = 1:0.1:5
yc = 1:0.1:5

p1 = contour(xc, yc, gitp_quad2d, fill=true)

plot(p1)
```

However this gives a plot without any contour curves on it, with a message saying "Arrays have incorrect length or dimension.". But the `contour` function seems to accept, as in the link above, arbitrary x, y arrays and a function of x, y, and returns a contour plot. This should not give rise to any dimension problems. What is wrong with the code?

[Edit]

```
using Interpolations
using Plots
gr()

xs = 1:0.5:5
ys = 1:0.5:8
g = Float64[(3x + y ^ 2) for x in xs, y in ys]
f(x, y) = (3x + y ^ 2)

g_int = interpolate(g, BSpline(Quadratic(Line(OnCell()))))

gs_int = scale(g_int, xs, ys)

xc = 1:0.1:5
yc = 1:0.1:5

println("gs_int(3.2, 3.2) = ", gs_int(3.2, 3.2))
println("f(3.2, 3.2) = ", f(3.2, 3.2))

p1 = contour(xs, ys, gs_int(xs, ys), fill=true)
p2 = contour(xc, yc, f, fill=true)

plot(p1, p2)
```

The result:
[image: a]

The interpolation seems to work fine but the result from the contour plot doesn't seem to convey the same message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify at what points you want  the  interpolation to happen - otherwise you will just get the  input resolution of the interpolated object, which is different from that of the new xc and yc (try `size(gitp_quad2d)`. There isn't a recipe built into Plots for doing that automatically on the x and y inputs.
Try

```
contourf(xc, yc, gitp_quad2d[xc, yc])
```

EDIT: updated to reflect update of question

On your plot, the reason you have the contour looking strangely is that your interpolated matrix is transposed relative to the x and y variables. The transposition expected of contour/heatmaps is always a discussion in plotting (should it be the same as matrices, as a normal plot or as an image? - see this issue for a good discussion https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Makie.jl/issues/205). Anyway, transposing it back will help (either `p1 = contourf(xs, ys, gs_int(xs, ys)')` or `p1 = contourf(xs, ys, gs_int(xs, ys), transpose = true)`

Comment: I tried it, it gave me a plot, but with a warning message: ┌ Warning: `getindex(itp::AbstractInterpolation{T, N}, i::Vararg{ExpandedIndexTypes, N}) where {T, N}` is deprecated, use `itp(i...)` instead.
│   caller = top-level scope at In[7]:13
└ @ Core In[7]:13

Comment: And the plot is obviously something else, which does not describe the shape of the function and looks heavily distorted

Comment: And I also tried `contourf(xc, yc, gitp_quad2d(xc, yc))`, the warning message is gone, but the contour plot is still heavily distorted (when I compare it with a plot which I got using the function itself instead of the interpolated one).

Comment: That's because the quadratic interpolation doesn't accurately guess the actual underlying function. So there's nothing wrong with the code here, nor with the plotting, it's just that Interpolation isn't exact. Try defining `f(xs, ys) = Float64[(3x + y ^ 2) * abs(sin(x) + cos(y)) for x in xs, y in ys]` then compare `f(xc, yc)` with `gitp_quad2d[xc, yc]`

Comment: Please take a look at my new code and the result. Although the interpolation seems to work fine, the contour plot is extremely distorted and this doesn't seem to be caused by an inaccurate interpolation ... The contour plot is distorted even if I take the same `(xc, yc)` and `(xs, ys)` ...

Comment: @Sato it looks like your interpolated matrix is transposed relative to the x and y variables. The transposition expected of contour/heatmaps is always a discussion in plotting (should it be the same as matrices, as a normal plot or as an image?). Anyway, transposing it back will help (either `p1 = contourf(xs, ys, gs_int(xs, ys)')` or `p1 = contourf(xs, ys, gs_int(xs, ys), transpose = true)`

Comment: Thank you. That worked, at least for the example I gave. But when I used some other data points (which was some randomly generated points in 2D space), this method didn't give the correct contour with transposition. It is correct without transposition. So I don't understand, when should I do transposition, and when shouldn't I?